# Issue with LSTMs in Keras with Tensorflow version 1.0.0-rc1

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I use Tensorflow as the backend in my keras. I upgraded both today, my keras version is 1.2.1, Tensorflow version is 1.0.0-rc1

I used LSTMs in a simple example

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense 
from keras.layers import LSTM

look_back = 1 
batch_size = 1 
model = Sequential()  
model.add(LSTM(4, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1), stateful=True, return_sequences=True))
```

It worked fine in the previous version of Tensorflow 0.9.0

Now, I get an error

> TypeError: Expected int32, got
>    of
>   type 'Variable' instead.

in the LSTM line.

Tensorflow released the current version a week ago. Any suggestions about this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems keras 1 doesn't work with tensorflow 1.0.0

See: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5443